# eth0 is proxy-arping, but /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp is 0

Tags: debian, mac-address, spoofing, proxy-arp

I'm scratching my head about this question... I have a debian squeeze machine that is connected to an internal lab network.  We have a lot of machines that have default proxy-arp configurations on them, and occasionally one of those machines starts hijacking a lot of lab addresses.

After resolving the latest Proxy-ARP incident which brought down most of our lab, I found a few residual entries like this in `/var/log/syslog` (below).  For those not accustomed to reading `arpwatch` logs, the machine that owns `00:11:43:d2:68:65` is fighting with 192.168.12.102 and 192.168.12.103 about who owns those address.

```
Sep 13 14:25:27 netwiki arpwatch: flip flop 192.168.12.103 00:11:43:d2:68:65 (84:2b:2b:4b:71:b4) eth0
Sep 13 14:26:24 netwiki arpwatch: flip flop 192.168.12.103 84:2b:2b:4b:71:b4 (00:11:43:d2:68:65) eth0
Sep 13 14:29:03 netwiki arpwatch: flip flop 192.168.12.102 00:26:b9:4e:d3:71 (00:11:43:d2:68:65) eth0
Sep 13 14:29:03 netwiki arpwatch: flip flop 192.168.12.102 00:11:43:d2:68:65 (00:26:b9:4e:d3:71) eth0
```

The very alarming thing is that `00:11:43:d2:68:65` belongs to the same machine I was running `arpwatch` on... First, I validated that `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp` is `0`.  Next, I used `tshark` to validate that my machine really is spoofing ARPs to others...

```
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$ ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:43:d2:68:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.12.239/24 brd 192.168.12.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::211:43ff:fed2:6865/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$ arp -an
? (192.168.12.46) at 00:15:c5:f5:81:9d [ether] on eth0
? (192.168.12.236) at 00:1e:c9:cd:46:c8 [ether] on eth0
? (10.211.180.1) at 00:1e:49:11:fe:47 [ether] on eth1
? (192.168.12.20) at f0:4d:a2:02:81:66 [ether] on eth0
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp
0
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$ sudo tshark -i eth0 arp and ether src 00:11:43:d2:68:65
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on eth0
  0.000000 Dell_d2:68:65 -> Dell_02:81:66 ARP 192.168.12.102 is at 00:11:43:d2:68:65
 84.954989 Dell_d2:68:65 -> Dell_f5:81:9d ARP 192.168.12.103 is at 00:11:43:d2:68:65
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$ uname -a
Linux netwiki 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 14 09:42:28 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$
```

The facts are undeniable.  I have a debian box that is spoofing ARPs and I have no idea why.  I am the only user on this machine, I run `fail2ban` to prevent brute-force attacks, and it's on an internal lab network behind a door that requires a badge for entry; I highly doubt it has been hacked.

Three questions...

1. First, is there any cause I may have missed?  What steps should I use to isolate whether this is an application or kernel problem?
2. If this is a kernel bug, which mailing-list should I report it on?  FYI, the normal [kernel.org bug reporting tool](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/docs/lkml/reporting-bugs.html) seems to be down right now.
3. Is there anything I can do to to solve the problem other than waiting for a patch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem... I was demonstrating how proxy-arp worked on a spare ethernet interface a few weeks ago and left the configs on the machine (although I had the interface DOWN).

When I removed these entries for `192.168.12.0/24` from `eth2`, I no longer had the problem.

```
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$ ip add show eth2
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:10:18:02:32:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.12.100/24 scope global eth2
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 scope global eth2
    inet 192.168.12.101/24 scope global secondary eth2
    inet 192.168.12.102/24 scope global secondary eth2
    inet 192.168.12.103/24 scope global secondary eth2
    inet 192.168.12.104/24 scope global secondary eth2
    inet 192.168.12.105/24 scope global secondary eth2
[mpenning@netwiki ~]$
```

I still think this is a bug and it needs to be filed.  I will update with the bug information when it is completed.